# Violation 'message' handler took <N>ms

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, google-chrome, socket.io

I create Chat web with the help of socket.io ,nodejs ,react .
when i send message there is some message or warnnig is commes in console
message :-[Violation] 'message' handler took ms
and also when i send message again and again the ms is increase by 200% ,
In starting of chat there is no warnning.

[Violation] 'message' handler took 167ms

2.05537ff6.chunk.js:2 [Violation] 'message' handler took 205ms

2.05537ff6.chunk.js:2 [Violation] 'message' handler took 389ms

2.05537ff6.chunk.js:2 [Violation] 'message' handler took 496ms

2.05537ff6.chunk.js:2 [Violation] 'message' handler took 1162ms

```
        import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
        import queryString from 'query-string';
        import io from 'socket.io-client';
        import './Chat.css'
        import InfoBar from './../InfoBar/InfoBar'
        import Input from './../Input/Input'
        import Messages from './../Messages/Messages'
        let socket;
        const Chat = ({ location }) => {
               const [name, setName] = useState('');
               const [room, setRoom] = useState('');
               const [message,setMessage]=useState('')
               const [messages,setMessages]=useState([])
               const ENDPOINT = 'https://d-chating.herokuapp.com/';
               useEffect(() => {
                        const { name, room } = queryString.parse(location.search)
    
    var connectionOptions = {
        "force new connection": true,
        "reconnectionAttempts": "Infinity",
        "transports": ["websocket"]
    };

    socket = io.connect(ENDPOINT, connectionOptions);
    setName(name);
    setRoom(room);
    socket.emit('join', { name, room },(error)=>{
       if(error){

           alert(error);
       }
    });


   
      },
      [ENDPOINT, location.search]
      )

      useEffect(()=>{
          socket.on('message',(message)=>{
              // console.log(message)
             setMessages([...messages,message]); 
          })
      },[messages]);


        const sendMessage =(event)=>{
            event.preventDefault();
                  if(message){
                socket.emit('sendMessage',message,()=>setMessage(''));
            }
        }
              // console.log(messages)
            return (
                <div className="outerContainer">
                    <div className='container'>
                        <InfoBar room={room} />
                  <Messages messages={messages} name={name} />
                 <Input message={message} sendMessage={sendMessage} setMessage={setMessage}/>
             
              </div>
          </div>
      )
        }
        export default Chat;
```